# Measure of intersection of infinitely many events with fixed positive measure

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ is a probability space (so $\mu:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow[0,1]$).

Suppose we have a countable collection of events $A_k\in \mathcal{B}$ such that for some fixed $\epsilon>0$, $\mu(A_k)>\epsilon$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Is it necessarily the case that there is some infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, $(k_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$, such that $\mu(\displaystyle{\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}} A_{n_k})>0$?

If this is true, can we be more specific? Like, require that some infinite sub collection of these have intersection whose measure is greater than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, or even $\epsilon$?

Intuitively, this seems to be the case: that if you have infinitely many sets all with some positive measure greater than some fixed thing, it seems like infinitely many of them should have to "overlap" in some sense.  I'm not a probability theorist though, in the past my intuition about these things has lead me astray.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No.

Consider Lebesgue measure on $[0,1)$. Let $$A_1=[0,1/2),$$
$$A_2=[0,1/4)\cup[1/2,3/4),$$
$$A_3=[0,1/8)\cup[1/4,3/8)\cup[1/2,5/8)\cup[3/4,7/8),$$
and so on.

Then $m(A_n)=1/2$ for all $n$, but the intersection of any $k$ of the sets $A_n$ has measure $2^{-k}$, so the intersection of any sequence has measure $0$. (The same holds for any sequence of *independent* events with probability $1/2$.)

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to pick arbitrarily (but finitely) many so that their intersection has positive measure? That is, for any $n$, $k_1,\ldots,k_n$ such that $\mu(A_{k_1}\cap\ldots\cap A_{k_n})>0$? Thanks again!

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: Yeah, so in that example it's the case that the intersection of finitely many of them has positive measure. But in general does that have to be true? As in my original question, if you just know that $\mu(A_k)>\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. I'm asking is it possible to choose an arbitrarily long but finite subsequence whose intersection has positive measure. The example you gave just says that you can't necessarily choose an infinitely long one such that that's the case.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. Yes. Say $f_k$ is the indicator function of $A_n$. Monotone convergence shows that $\int\sum f_k=\infty$. So $\sum f_k$ cannot be essentially bounded; hence for any $n$ the set $\{\sum f_k>n\}$ has positive measure, and hence the same is true for $\sum_{k=1}^N f_k$ for suitable $N$.